# .htacess mod_rewrite slim routing

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, slim

I have two kinds of routes.

This works:

```
http://localhost/monitor/test1
```

This does not:

```
http://localhost/monitor/test2/test3
```

Here is my current rule:

```
RewriteRule (^[^/]*$) public/$1 [L]
```

I know this one only matches the last slash. How can I change the regex to match both cases?

Comment: Could you please do let us know from `http://localhost/monitor/test2/test3` to which url you want to redirect?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i want to redirect to public/test2/test3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/monitor[^/]*/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/%1 [NC,L]
```

OR in case you could have any other string other than `monitor` in `REQUEST_URI` starting part then please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]*/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/%1 [NC,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Or we can catch values in while writing `RewriteRule` itself and could reduce 1 `RewriteCond` which is used in 1st solution here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
```

OR with `monitor` matching keyword:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^monitor[^/]*/(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You have already helped me a lot, i am really greatfull.
The one that worked for me is the first one but for the record the public directory must not start with slash

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/monitor[^/]*/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/%1 [NC,L]

Comment: @DiegoDieh, your welcome :)  But actually that slash will make REQUEST URI after domain name of URL hence it was present there, happy to help cheers